# In the original timeline, who was the Destroyer of Worlds?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

When Daisy and company went to the future, it was widely believed that she was the one who destroyed the Earth. This was partly the basis of her entering a city before it was destroyed: fairly thin evidence, admittedly, but it was widely believed. Later, Talbot seemed to be on track to be the one to destroy the planet.

However, other possibilities were subsequently floated: Ruby and ultimately Talbot. As we see, ultimately they could change things, so it *could*, say, have been Daisy originally.

Was the Destroyer of Worlds always Talbot in the original timeline? Was it instead Daisy? Or possibly even Ruby?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was Talbot enhanced with Daisy's powers in the original timeline.

In both timelines, the team spends its resources on the Centipede serum for Coulson to use. In the destroyed world timeline, he either uses it, or otherwise doesn't hand it to Daisy, according to future Yo-Yo (Episode 5.10, *Past Life*).  It's that secret handoff of the serum from Coulson to Daisy that ultimately breaks the loop.

During the finale, the same events Deke showed to Daisy back in the future (Episode 5.02, *Orientation Part Two*) are shown again to the viewers, with Daisy getting off the Quinjet and looking back to speak to its occupants, before rushing off to battle in the evacuated Chicago (the show even treats us to the same distant camera shot used in the newsreel). The timeline at this point is thus the same as the original for everyone except Coulson, who has handed off the serum.

In this original timeline, Talbot would successfully absorb Daisy, incorporating her powerset to more quickly mine the planet for Gravitonium, which ultimately triggered the 12.8 quake that would eventually destroy the planet.  Neither of them individually are capable of breaking apart the planet, but by their powers combined, they are Captain Destructo-Planet, Destroyer of Worlds.

Comment: Seems plausible, but a) why would they say the city had already been evacuated? It hadn't been at that point. And, b) why wouldn't anyone have mentioned Talbot? Y'know, the floating guy who landed his alien spaceship in Chicago right before whatever happened to the planet and started tearing up the ground?

Comment: @Adamant I can't answer the first question ("evacuated" tends to happen magically in TV shows with limited budget, where a city like Chicago is mostly evacuated within 5 minutes of a main cast member saying "we need to evacuate the city!").

Comment: As for the second part, it appears from Deke's Framework paradise that the only surviving footage of the Chicago incident.  Daisy is a known public figure and Inhuman Agent of Shield, while Talbot was really last known to the public as the general that Daisy (really an LMD) assassinated.  Presumably most of Chicago's populace perished being close to the epicenter, and who knows if any got to the Lighthouse.  The surviving SHIELD agents all hid their status in the Lighthouse, so they aren't speaking the truth.  Taken altogether, it leaves Daisy and SHIELD as easy scapegoats.

Comment: Another neat fact was that Robin colors in large parts of Talbot's globe with the Black Marker -- the same bits that the Earth was fractured along, in fact!